# RSpec Rails syntax helpers

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails

I'm using rspec-rails v3.4.2. I see many examples on the Web as follows

```
describe "My Test Suite" do
  # ...
end

feature "My Awesome Feature" do
  # ...
end
```

And I have something similar for FactoryGirl, to write `create(:model)` instead of typing the full version, `FactoryGirl.create(:model)`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

Is it the same for the RSpec syntax methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default you can use `describe`, `shared_examples` and so on without `RSpec` prefix. Please also check https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/configuration/global-namespace-dsl for details